# calculo entre duas datas definidas

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código em `PHP`:

```
$valor = 120;
$data_inicio = '2016-06-15';

$total_dias = date('t', strtotime($data_inicio));
$used = date('d', strtotime($data_inicio));

$result = ($valor/$total_dias)*$used;

echo $result;
```

Ele me retorna qual foi o valor gasto do dia *01/06* até *15/06*, com uma base de **120,00** por mês.

Queria saber como fazer isso com 2 datas diferentes.

*Exemplo:*

```
$data1 = '2016-06-16';
$data2 = '2016-07-01';
```

O resultado tem que ser **56,00**

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

    function dateDiff($firstDate, $lastDate) {
        $firstDate = new DateTime($firstDate);
        $lastDate = new DateTime($lastDate);

        $intervalo = $firstDate->diff($lastDate);
        print "{$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias"; 
    }
    $data1 = '2016-06-16';
    $data2 = '2016-08-01';

    print_r(dateDiff($data1, $data2));

?>
```

Certamente esse código irá te ajudar a trabalhar com as diferenças entre datas visto que você usa o total de dias e os *dias de diferença* na variável chamada: **$used**.

Comment: muito bom isso obrigado